# Efficiently updating listitems of a displayed list in a list fragment by background threads

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` and a custom `ArrayAdapter` and I pass to the adapter an arraylist of custom objects and are displayed in my list fragment. Example in pseudocode

```
public class ContactsFragment extends ListFragment {  
  private ArrayList<Contacts> contacts;  
  // rest of code  
  private class ContactAdapter extextends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> users) {
       super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // inflate list item and add info for the UI  
      return convertView;
     }  
}
```

Step 1:  The UI displays the list of contacts.
Step 2:  `Contact` class has a member URL that I have to do a JSON call to get the contact's status and show it in the list item.
Step 3:  For each element of `ArrayList<Contact>` therefore I need to do a JSON call and update the listitem.
Right now I have spinner bar defined in my list item's layout to be replaced after the corresponding JSON call.
Problem:
How can I efficiently update the listitems displayed accessing the URL of each one? Basically I would have to update the arraylist shared by the custom array adapter with the new info per list item

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question by dividing your approach in steps. Example : Step 1 : Create a ListFragement. Step 2 : Create an ArrayAdapter. Step 3 :Create a list of custom objects. Also, some pseudo code would help to understand what you mean. The question as it stands is too long for most SO users to stop by and answer.

Comment: @bot:Updated OP. Is this better? Should I add/remove something?

Comment: This is much more readable now. Unfortunately, I don't seem to have an answer for you.